# Insert pwd on exec command

Tags: linux, bash

When i run this commannd:
`find . -name "*.sh" -exec ls -ltrh {} ;`, i have this output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7.0K Jun 24 19:37 ./ubuntu.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.8K Jun 24 19:35 ./centos.sh
```

I want to insert the pwd command to see where is location of ubuntu and centos .sh.
I want to know how to solve tthis problem

Answer (score 0):

```
find \`pwd\` -name "*.sh" -exec ls -ltrh {} \\;
```

Should do it. That's backquotes around pwd.

Comment: When i type find \`pwd\` -name "*.sh" -exec ls -ltrh {} \\; i have this output: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: @Bib why do you escape the backticks? use `find $(pwd) -name "*.sh" -exec -ltrh {} ";"` instead - no weird quoting, no weird escapes

Comment: I would like them to show me all the .sh files on the server and show me their location. This command only shows me the .sh files in the current directory.

Comment: I escaped them as when I originally did it, the backquotes did not show up in the answer.

Comment: If you want to find all .sh files, then the use '/' rather than '.'.

Comment: root@vps1052148:/tmp# find $(pwd) -name "*.sh" -exec ls -ltrh /{}^C
root@vps1052148:/tmp# find $(pwd) -name "*.sh" -exec ls -ltrh {} "/"
find: missing argument to `-exec'
root@vps1052148:/tmp# find $(pwd) -name "*.sh" -exec ls -ltrh {} '/'
find: missing argument to `-exec'
root@vps1052148:/tmp# find $(pwd) -name "*.sh" -exec ls -ltrh {} '.'
find: missing argument to `-exec'
root@vps1052148:/tmp# find $(pwd) -name "*.sh" -exec ls -ltrh {} "."

Comment: `$(pwd)` calls another process, try `${PWD}`.

Comment: What i want is to find all the .sh files on a server and i want to show me their location.

Comment: find / -name "*.sh" -exec ls -ltrh {} \;